# R - Error building packages - cannot install to srcdir

Tags: r, package

Hi I am trying to build a basic package on a new computer. I have created the new "hello world" package from New -> create project -> package. I have then run the package check which comes back with no errors and also passes the "checking whether package 'test3' can be installed" step.  When I try to install I get the error message

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source test3

* installing to library 'C:/R_packages'
ERROR: cannot install to srcdir for package 'test3'
* removing 'C:/R_packages/test3'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It seems you are using a custom library folder. Can you try to reset default lib and build from there (to see if it is permission pb). ?

Comment: The default is a UNC path which is not permitted